# JS Jquery Namespace Calling Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok terrible title but I couldn't think of another description.

I have the following code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) 
{
    $.myNamespace = {
          init: function()
          {

             $('.button').click(function() {
                  this.anotherFunction();
             });
          },
          anotherFunction: function()
          {
               alert('insidefunction');
          }
    }
    $.myNamespace.init();
});
```

As you can see I am trying to call anotherFunction from inside init and have there the two ways I tried but didn't work.  So how am I able to call that function or is my concept wrong?

Comment: Assuming you haven't bound things to a different context, how about `this.anotherFunction()`?

Comment: actually I tried that too...still comes back with "is not a function" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ )
{
    $.myNamespace = {
          init: function()
          {
             var a=this;
             $('.button').click(function() {
                  a.anotherFunction();
             });
          },
          anotherFunction: function()
          {
               alert('insidefunction');
          }
    }
    $.myNamespace.init();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpAtm/2/

Comment: yes either that works or I just found out you can also do: $.myNamespace.anotherFunction()...But may I ask if it is necessary to make antoherFunction separate?  Can I not just put it inside "init" function so I wouldn't have this problem in the first place?

Comment: @Rick Yes you could do that as well.

Comment: I guess I just don't know what the benefit is in separating out the functions like that...I am only doing it because I am follow practices by other developers but I don't have a full grasp on why to do it.....thanks...

Comment: As a small tip, most people tend to call a variable set to the value of `this` either `that` or `self`. Following naming conventions like that helps make your code easier to understand by other developers.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely calling it within the click handler changes things, as `this` inside any jQuery event handler is set to the element that caused the event.

Instead, try using the following pattern:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.myNamespace = (function() {
        function init() {
            $('.button').click(function() {
                anotherFunction();
            });
        }

        function anotherFunction() {
            alert('insidefunction');
        }

        // return an object with all the functions you want 
        // available publically as properties. Don't include
        // any "private" functions.
        return {
            init: init,
            anotherFunction: anotherFunction
        };
    })();
    $.myNamespace.init();
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for that insight.  If I was solely doing this just to have a namespace so to prevent conflicts, then I could literally just put everything (all functions) inside "init", would that be correct to say?

Comment: @Rick Yes, I believe that would also work. The only time that Javascript creates a new scope is inside functions. Other blocks (`if`, `for`, etc) do not create a new scope. Also make sure you understand the principle of JS "hoisting".